# Adding logging for an object inside catch block

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, exception, try-catch

I want to handle exceptions in code in a way that during the processing of an object if an exception arises, then in the catch block I want to log the object that caused this exception.

My code:

```
public String handleRequest(KinesisEvent kinesisEvent, Context context) {
        try {
            List<myObj> allObj = kinesisEvent.getRecords().stream()
                           .map(it -> it.getKinesis().getData())
                           .filter(ByteBuffer::hasArray)
                           .map(byteBuffer -> new String(byteBuffer.array(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                           .map(dataInString -> jsonSerDe.fromJson(dataInString, myObj.class))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());

            //some code
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
           // Here I want to log out the particular `dataInString` string 
           // that caused the exception to be trigerred. 

           logger.error("Parsing input to myObj failed: {}", ex.getMessage(), ex);
            
        }
```

Comment: That is not possible with streams. You would need to use for-loops for that and even then you need custom code to make anything from the try available in the catch.

Comment: @luk2302 - not true. The OP could create a function that wraps `jsonSerDe.fromJason` in a try/catch, and log from within that function. I believe (but haven't tried) that it doesn't even need a defined function, but the lambda could contain the try/catch (I can never remember whether Java lambdas are limited to expressions or can contain statements).

Comment: That would work but cause two stack traces to be logged, one from the inner lambda, one from the handleRequest, might be okay for OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try/catch block works inside map function.

```
public String handleRequest(KinesisEvent kinesisEvent, Context context) {
    try {
        List<myObj> allObj = kinesisEvent.getRecords().stream()
                .map(it -> it.getKinesis().getData())
                .filter(ByteBuffer::hasArray)
                .map(byteBuffer -> new String(byteBuffer.array(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                .map(dataInString -> {
                    try {
                        return jsonSerDe.fromJson(dataInString, myObj.class);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex){
                        logger.error("Parsing input to myObj failed inside stream : {}", dataInString);
                        //throw new RuntimeException("problem string: " + dataInString); //or your custom exception class
                    }

                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //some code
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // Here I want to log out the particular `dataInString` string
        // that caused the exception to be trigerred.

        logger.error("Parsing input to myObj failed: {}", ex.getMessage(), ex);

    }
}
```

can you try this?

Comment: You need to return the value of `jsonSerDe.fromJson()`.

Comment: Looks good, but the IDE gives an error "missing return statement". Probably because `return` is mentioned in the try block. Any workarounds?